# Solenoid Driver Circuit

Tags: arduino, mosfet, solenoid, mosfet-driver, solenoid-valve

I want to drive a solenoid (12V load and 20A rating) using a MOSFET and an Arduino. What kind of switching circuit should I use?

Comment: What is the control input?

Comment: Based on the tags, I bet the control is 5V logic.

Answer (score 1):

N-channel MOSFET with logic level gate drive, low (sub 1 ohm) Rdson connected to coil, the other end of the coil connected to the 12 volt supply.

See schematic and ignore the values listed (don't have time to do the math and spec in proper components).  You might have to have a gate driver, depends on the logic level of the mosfet and the efficiency you are trying to get. The diode is for back EMF.  Choose MOSFET based on current, gate threshold voltage, and Vgs value.

You can even use a PWM signal to control the current into the coil, but you'd need a current feedback circuit (easy but not in schematic listed).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZPBJF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Gee - I just answered an almost identical question a few minutes ago .

My "go-to" part for low-voltage, medium current DC switching is the IRF3708. 30V, 62A continuous, 0.012 Ohms Rds on. Drive the gate with a 47 Ohm resistor mounted as close to the gate as possible.

The FET shouldn't need a heatsink - 0.012 Ohms * 20A = 0.24 Watts.